# Bezier editing tool - problem with plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, editing, tools

Have been using Bezier editing tool for  a while in QGIS but for some reason I couldn't find it anymore. When I tried to install it again I was recieving this message :

Python error : Couldn't load plugin 'BezierEditing' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method See message log (Python Error) for more details.

I have the QGIS 3.16 VERSION and for the plugin to work it needs minimum QGIS 3.0. I have tried to download it and install it as a zip file but still not working...

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The plugin uses the `QgsSettingsRegistryCore` class, which appeared in version 3.20, so it will not work in 3.16. You need to use the new version of Qgis for this plugin. Or find an old version of the plugin. Or rewrite its code without using `QgsSettingsRegistryCore`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked now